# JQuery Quickfix : I don't know how to call it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML:

```
  <ul class="test">
   <li><a href="#">One</a>
    <ul>
     <li>Content One</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Two</a>
    <ul>
     <li>Content Two</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

I want to hide `UL.TEST LI UL`. When I click anchor "one" or when I click "ul.test li" or "ul.test li a"

How will I do it without using a CLASS or ID in the "ul.test li ul"?

My code is:

```
  $(function(){
   $("ul.test li").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).slideToggle("fast");
   });
  });
```

What I want to do:

```
  $(this + "ul").slideToggle("fast");
```

I want to hide only `ul.test li ul` only.

what if?

```
$("ul.test li a").click(function(e){
  $('ul', this).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

how will I go back to `ul.test li` using `$('ul', this).slideToggle("fast");`

Comment: Do you not control the target HTML, or is there a specific reason you're not using functional selectors like class names or ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("ul.test li").click(function(e){
  $('ul', this).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9KAhT/

```
$("ul.test li a").click(function(e){
   $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: In that case, you need to use this `$(this).next().slideToggle("fast");` instead of `$('ul', this)...`

Comment: @bEjnicbEj If this is the answer you like best, you should press the green checkmark next to it to mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
$(this).find("ul").slideToggle("fast");
```

inside your click handler

EDIT:

maybe this will be of more use to you. http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/